# Mod_Rewrite with Query Strings In Pretty URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file that redirects all URLs to the index.php file with a route query string parameter:

```
# Enable Mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect pretty URLs to the index file
RewriteRule ^([\w\/\-]+)/?$ index.php?route=$1
```

This works great, with the exception of URLs with query strings in them. For example, I have a form that redirects back to the login screen with an error code (`/admin/login?error=1`). Obviously, the problem is, the `$_GET[error]` parameter is never passed to the main script.

How would I get these parameters passed to the script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add [[QSA]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) as a flag:

> 'qsappend|QSA' (query string append) This flag forces the rewrite
>   engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the
>   existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to
>   add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

`RewriteRule ^([\w\/\-]+)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]`

Answer (score 3):

This is my standard mod_rewrite entry (altered for your question). I'm adding it to save anyone potential pain with stuff like images & includes. It redirects everything except existing files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\w\/\-]+)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful snippet :)

Comment: It not allowing special character like .,$&.  How we can allow this.

Answer (score 2):

Set the flag QSA - Query String Append

```
# Enable Mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect pretty URLs to the index file
RewriteRule ^([\w\/\-]+)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
```

(All I did was add the [QSA] )

The Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation has more on flags.